# How double equality executed

Tags: python

As expressions are executed left to right but when I execute this given double equality it gives me false but it should be True if executed left to right.

```
print(1<0<1)
```

left to right it should be executed like this.

```
# 1<0 = False(0),
```

then

```
# 0<1 = True(1)
```

so the expression becomes True and I get False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is weird but Python does not executes it left to right. It is executed as

```
print(1<0 and 0<1)
```

so as left of **and** is false which makes whole equation false due to **and** operator.
This is the reason you are getting False.

Comment: Think of it as "1 is less than 0 which is less than 1"